# List element using property string path

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I am not sure if this is possible or not.

Lets say a I have class `C1` that have a `List<double>` inside:

```
class C1{
    List<double> theList {get;set}
    double someVar {get;}
}
```

I can get `somevar` through the string path `"C1.somevar"` and the same thing is valid for the list. However, is there a way for me to use string paths to retrieve a specific element of the list? Something like `"C1.theList.0"`

The reason behind is that in OxyPlot I want to be able to set the `DataFielY`of a `LineSeries` to a specific element in the list.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `"C1.theList[0]"`?

Comment: Show your current code. Or rather, see any of the duplicates.

Comment: @juharr this question is about reflection, accessing a collection element by index, using a string.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not familiar with oxyplot so I was just throwing out a suggestion.

Comment: @juharr I suspect reflection purely based on the phrase "string path", so we're both guessing. ;)

Comment: if you want to speed up the guessing game, you can add further information to your post to describe a little more in detail what you are trying to do and what exactly you mean with **string path**. do you have an actual example how you "get `somevar` through the string path "C1.somevar""

Comment: @JulianoFranz it's long time since I last used OxyPlot, I don't remember what it is uses (especially in newer versions) to resolve the property value. Possible workarounds: if it supports dynamic types (just try) you can have your own collection with `ExpandoObject` where items (0, 1, ...) are in fact properties. To do it you have to cast the `ExpandoObject` to `IDictionary<string, object>` and binding path may be `C1.theList.0` as you wish. If OxyPlot does not support this (highly possible) you still can add support for yourself...

Comment: 2) Alternatively, if I remember correctly, there is a `Mapping` property you can use for _custom_ mapping between items in `ItemsSource` and `DataPoint`.